# prevent refresh of my jsp page on submit button clicked

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0

I am working on jee project, When I am clicking the submit button, the function of the button is right but the page is refreshing so the data that i entered on text field for example will be deleted!!!

the code of my jsp is:

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="submit" name="random_generator" width="200" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Random Task Generator">
 </div>
```

the code on servlet.java:

```
if (request.getParameter("random_generator") != null) {
        al.clear();
        control.clear();

        i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));
        u = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("max"));

        b = ta.Random_Tasks_Generator(i, u);
        String z = "you have " + i + " tasks," + "\n" + " you must choose a single task to complete the work";
        request.setAttribute("btn", z);

    }
```

What should I do to prevent the page refresh?

[image]

Comment: What about posting the HTML with the inputs? That would seem relevant to the discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i get while executing my code. i must enter the numbre of tasks a the maximum of utilization factor then i click on random tasks generator to get the list of tasks. when i click on  the button, the page refresh and the data (nb tasks and utilization factor) are deleted and i need to them later !!